Calculate current with Thévenin's theorem

Calculate the current going through the first resistor (2 ohms)
First, let's find Thévenin's voltage: we take off the last 2ohm resistor and calculate the voltage difference between that open circuit
After that I shut off all sources and calculate the passive resistances, where 2 and 4 are in series and 6 being parallel to them, getting:

I, however am conflicted as to have I taken the correct load resistor out. I feel conflicted due to previously only worked with circuits where it's usually just easy to see which of the resistors is the clear-cut choice for cutting.
I also couldn't find any similar examples at this time. Any help getting me understanding the principles of these kinds of exercises is greatly appreciated.

Are you required to use Thevenin for this problem or was that your choice? Which is the "first 2 ohm resistor" and which is the "last 2 ohm resistor"? (adding designators on your schematic would make this more clear) Which component or network are you considering the load for the purposes of making the Thevenin equivalent?  The existing answers have given alternate methods of solving the problem, but none has told you where your solution went wrong. If you can clarify what you did, it might be possible to help you with that too.

Iam lost, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

My question is: If voltage over R_3 is 0V, then thievenins voltage over the first 2-ohm resistor (the resistor connected to the same point as the one where voltage is zero) is the same as voltage of the voltage source, which is 10 V. But this makes no sense to me and I am kind of lost with calculating the thievenins resistance when we have the 0-voltage resistor there; am I supposed to account it with or without when trying to build up the Thevenins source over the load resistor? I apologize for not realizing that questions stay active, I'll try to be better.

I cannot help you if things make no sense other than to advise you to stick at it.

Using source transformation your circuit is equivalent to this: -

All I've done is use another voltage source and removed the upper central conductor. There is no change in functionality or performance. Then, it's easy to convert the two voltage sources (each in series with 2 Ω) to equivalent current sources in parallel with 2 Ω: -

And clearly all of the current from the LH current source has to flow into the middle current source and, this means the parallel resistors (4 Ω and 2 Ω) take no current and thus can be shorted. This brings us to the next simplification: -

Do you see how simple and revealing this approach is?
Anyway, the voltage across the parallel combination of 6 Ω and 2 Ω has to be 1.5 Ω multiplied by 10 amps. That's 15 volts.
So now, you can go back to your original circuit (if you want) and mark the voltages on it: -

Anything else you want to calculate is trivial now.
Hint: Don't use math when simplification via source transformation is a much better route. In other words, think about the problem and get a deeper meaning about the circuit.

Very good explanation ...

This is a good solution, but it is using the Norton transformation rather than Thevenin. If OP is doing a homework where they are required to use Thevenin, they should be aware that this solution doesn't follow that requirement. (Though I agree that Norton is the better way to actually solve the problem)

@ThePhoton Thévenin's theorem (as mentioned in the OP's post) requires that two specific terminals are designated in order to collapse the circuit to a single voltage source and a resistor across those two points. The OP never stated those designators (first point). Nevertheless, if designators were presented (albeit a bit late in the day), I'm sure that an equivalent voltage source and resistor can be easily derived.

@Andyaka agreed. Norton's theorem also requires choosing two terminals as the outputs...which is exactly what you did in your answer and use it to come up with a solution to the overall problem.

I didn't choose any terminals TBH, I just simplified the circuit so that terminals can be chosen retrospectively.

The left, middle and right sections below are identical:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A current source has infinite resistance. So it is perfectly valid to break it into two pieces, as shown in the middle. And at that point, you really just have two different circuits shown on the right side.
Do you think you can work out what you need to know from the right pair? Use any technique you want.

Simulated with microcap v12.
It is a surprising circuit ... If \$ V1 = 10 V \$ then \$ir3 = 0 A \$.
Whatever the lower left resistance is, its voltage seems always to be \$ 0 V \$.
So, the current through the upper left resistor is always \$ 5 A \$.
Note also that if \$ R4 = 2 Ohm \$, then \$ i4 = 5 A \$  and \$ i2 = 0 \$.

Confirmed with Maple sheet.


Is it maybe due to current source resistance being infinite?

No. it is a "particularity" of this circuit. Note that if R4=2 Ohm, then i4 = 5 A and i2 = 0.
