Stuck on Thévenins algorithm

How do I get this diagram into Thévenins source, when the load resistor is \$R_1\$? With values: E=10V, J=5A, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ = 2 ohms, \$ R_3 \$= 4 ohms and \$R_4\$ = 6 ohms?
I know some things already (like the fact that the voltage over \$R_3\$ is 0V and that the \$I_1\$ is 5 amps, but I haven't gotten to the solution using Thévenins algorithm. I just can´t get my head around calculating Thévenins resistance.


To find Thevenin resistance, remove the voltage source E and connect a DC 1A current source. in its place .Connect the bottom nodes to GND. Use nodal analysis to measure the voltage at the top node.. That would be your DC thevenin resistance.

Our learning principle with finding out Thévenins resistance is that we should turn off all sources and just add up all resistors (excluding the one that is the load resistor) and that should be Thevenins resistance in this particular circuit. However, then if J has been replaced with an open circuit, the resistance is 2 ohms + 6 ohms and then adding the parallel 4 ohm resistor, we get 48/12=4 ohms. This makes no sense.

The thevenin resistance would be 6 || 8 ohms looking from E.

You have to open circuit J . Then the equivalent resistance of the network as seen by E is  $ (R_1 + R_3 ) ||( R_2 + R_4) $. Reading a book on circuit analysis would help you understand this

Yes but aren´t you supposed to leave out R_1 when calculating thevenins resistance over a passive circuit? As in the R_1 is then added later in a circuit with thevenins voltage source, resistor and R_1

Looking at the circuit, $R_1 $ is not the source resistance as it is connected to other resistors in parallel.  Source resistance in this circuit is zero ( ideallly )

Yes but how is thevenins resistance then calculated when the total resistance in this particular thevenins circuit should be R_1 connected to the two points coming from a thevenins circuit containing thevenins voltage source and thevenins resistor. Thevenins resistor then should not include R_1 in itself

Why do you think the thevenin resistance should be $R_1$ . Is there a reason? Try to think of the resistances and current source together as a box. Its resistance is the thevenin resistance.

Sorry, I meant that the component R_1 should be first removed completely from the circuit when beginning to calculate thevenins circuit. Then when we have calculated Thevenins resistance and Thevenins voltage source, we add the R_1 to that circuit as a component (if we think that without R_1 there would be an open circuit without it in a circuit containing thevenins voltage source and thevenins resistance.

You cant remove resistances as you want while calculating  overall resistance of the network . That would be illegal.

I've added how the circuit should look like in the end: Hope this clarifies.

$R_1$  is the load resistor. To calculate thevenin resistance, you have to remove it. Measure resistance as seen by its terminals.

Yes so wouldn't that then be ((R_2+R_4)*R_3)/((R_2+R_4)+R_3)

See this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/725730/calculate-current-with-th%c3%a9venins-theorem?noredirect=1#comment1930411_725730

These are two states you could use to work out the Thevenin equivalent, as seen by \$R_1\$:

(Not the only two ways to go, as any two different situations can be used to get there. But probably the easiest pair of situations.)
You make a decision where \$0\:\text{V}\$ is located, as shown above, to start.
The open-circuit voltage, \$E_1\$, would then be computed quite easily. All of \$J\$ must be pulled through \$R_3\$. The more positive end of \$R_3\$ will be where the current arrow enters \$R_3\$. The more negative end of \$R_3\$ will be where the current arrow exits. With reference to \$0\:\text{V}\$ the (-) marked node will be negative. The (+) end will be equal to \$E\$. The difference is trivial to compute. That is the Thevenin voltage, \$V_{_\text{TH}}=E_1\$.
The short circuit current, \$I_1\$, is similarly easy. The voltage \$E\$ will be applied across \$R_3\$. This will generate a current, arrow pointing downward from the positive end towards the negative end. That current through \$R_3\$, plus the current \$J\$, is \$I_1\$. The Thevenin resistance is then \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{E_1}{I_1}\$.
That's all there is to it. Once you know these two, you can then find \$I_{R_1}=5\:\text{A}\$ when \$R_1=2\:\Omega\$. (Which will imply that \$I_{R_3}=0\:\text{A}\$.)

I think I finally get it now: E_1 is calculated with E+E_R3=10V+20V=30V. Here then we set short circuit and I_1 is then 7.5 amps, because current through R_3 is 2.5 amps so 5+2.5 amps is 7.5 amps. Then getting R_Th is 30/7.5 which is then 4 ohms. Did I get it correct

@iamLost Looks good to me! Very nice! :) Best wishes moving forward. I have great hopes for you! I'll add +1 to your question.

thank you so much! it just takes the right perspective to understand it truly. you brought me that perspective today :)

A Thevenin equivalent circuit refers to a pair of terminals. One must begin by identifying the pair of terminals at issue.
The problem refers to R1 as a load. A sensible interpretation (but not the only one- it is best when constructing problems to remove ambiguity) is to consider the pair of terminals to be the terminal pair after removing R1.
Then just apply the procedure(s) for finding the Thevenin equivalent at that terminal pair. The most general approach is to (1) evaluate the open circuit voltage and then (2) attach a test source (Vt or It) and calculate (It or Vt) after setting all independent sources to zero.
